# Scala fails to run compiled class, but runs it directly

Tags: java, scala, jvm

TL;DR: REPL runs object fine when I use the first variant, but everything, even successfully compiled code fails to run when I replace import test._ with package test in order to compile.

I have a simple Hello World app written in Scala:

```
import test._
object TestApp {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val p = new HelloWorldPrinter
    p.output()
  }
}
```

The HelloWorldPrinter.output() method is just `println("Hello World");`

When I run the app with `scala TestApp.scala` it works and outputs Hello World, however, when I run fsc or scalac on it to compile, it produces a subfolder of the same package name "test" and puts TestApp.class in there. Then, if I run `scala test/TestApp` it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: test/TestApp
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

However, if I `cd` into "test" to run the compiled classes from there, I get a completely different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestApp (wrong name: test/TestApp)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:50)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$tryClass$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$tryClass$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:104)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:104)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.tryClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.tryToLoadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.tryToLoadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.classExists(ScalaClassLoader.scala:120)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:34)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

What gives?

Edit:

This is my TestApp.scala object: https://gist.github.com/3863344

This is my Printers.scala class: https://gist.github.com/3863348

Running `scala test/TestApp` after compiling with fsc gives me the first error. Entering the `test` subfolder and running `scala TestApp` gives me the second error. Running `scala TestApp.scala` in the main folder gives me this:

```
TestApp.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
package test
^
one error found
```

Edit 2: I just found out that REPL cannot run code with package declarations, so I understand why the above error happens. I am still unable to run my compiled code, however.

Comment: Are you sure you not missing out `package test` somewhere - only then can the class end up in test folder, you should be able to execute it from outside test using `scala test.TestApp`

Comment: Interesting fact: If I replace "import test._" with "package test", I can no longer run the script uncompiled, BUT I can compile it and then successfully run it without going into the test build subfolder. No matter what I do, it seems I can't have the cake and eat it - I can either run the script while using import, or run the compiled class (which ends up outside the test folder) while using package.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen has the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was it - does my assumption in Petr's comment ring true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the compiled code as `scala test.TestApp` from the main folder (in the case of running compiled classes `scala` accepts class name as its argument, not a file name).

Scala (just as java) has a list of locations to search classes in - called *classpath*. By default, the location is set to the current directory. Then for given class `packageX.packageY.ClassName` it searches for the corresponding `.class` file `packageX/packageY/ClassName.class`. So if you run `scala test.TestApp` with no explicit classpath it locates the compiled file `test/TestApp.class` and runs it.

Comment: This works, but why? How does it know where the class is if I run it from outside the folder in which the class resides?

Comment: I understand now. When I compile, I get bytecode classes arranged by folder, each dot meaning a new level. When I say run test.TestApp, it implicitly knows it's in a subfolder called test. Were I to remove it from the test folder and then run either `scala TestApp` or `scala test.TestApp` neither would work because a class with a package requires that it's inside a folder tree with a path identical to the package name, correct? In that regard, it is impossible to run a class belonging to a package outside a package?

Comment: @Swader Yes, that's right. If you move the class outside the package folder, neither `scala` nor `java` will be able to load and run it.